# Disable Modifier Keys in AutoHotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I want to map control Ctrl+Left to Home and Ctrl+Right to End, and I'm using AutoHotkey, my script is simply this:

```
^Left::Home
^Right::End
```

However, when the Home and End keys are generated, they are interpreted at Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End because I'm holding down the Ctrl key to generate them. How can I disable the Ctrl key or any modifier key when reassigning keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can just use Send:

```
^Left::Send {Home}
^Right::Send {End}

;Doesn't work with Shift, so we can add that manually:

+^Left::Send +{Home}
+^Right::Send +{End}

;You can add any other modifier keys you need to work.
```

It appears using [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) will temporarily release any modifier keys already held down, so that the output of Send won't be affected by them -- unless you specifically use [{Blind}](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#blind) to preserve modifier keys already held down.

The `a::b` format is used to [remap keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) and preserves any modifiers held down. (It actually [internally uses Send {Blind}](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#SendPlay).)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
^Left::
KeyWait Control
Home
Return

^Right::
KeyWait Control
End
Return
```

If you just need any code for this and it doesn't need to be autohotkey, AuotIt should work:

```
HotKeySet("^{LEFT}", "Home")
HotKeySet("^{RIGHT}", "End")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func Home()
    Send("{HOME}")
EndFunc

Func End()
    Send("{END}")
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
    Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Comment: I guess this could kinda work, it would be really nice if AutoHotkey could just somehow disable modifier keys temporarily; I want this short cut for text editing in particular IDEs so having to release Ctrl before the line is skipped will be a bit annoying when I'm selecting a line to copy:
Shift+Ctrl+Left->Release Ctrl->Ctrl+C